Syntax for 'Filters' value when creating a discount item with API4
What is the proper syntax for the 'filters' value in API4? Trying to create a discount item that is applicable to certain membership types and event types.
E.g., here's what I've got, but it doesn't work, and the filters is the culprit (i.e., if I omit the filters line, it creates the discount item just fine, but without the event types, obviously... which I need for this use case):
$results = \Civi\Api4\DiscountCode::create(TRUE)
  ->addValue('code', $gcCode)
  ->addValue('description', 'gift certificate')
  ->addValue('amount', $gcAmount)
  ->addValue('amount_type', 2)
  ->addValue('count_max', 1)
  ->addValue('active_on', date("Y-m-d"))
  ->addValue('is_active', TRUE)
  ->addValue('memberships', [
    1,
    3,
    7,
  ])
  ->addValue('filters.event.event_type_id', [
    1,
    2,
    11,
  ])
  ->execute();

Thank you for any pointers.

OK, so through some trial and error, figured out the following syntax for the filters value to limit the discount to specific event types:
->addValue('filters', [
    'event' => ['event_type_id' => ['IN' => ['1', '2', '11']]],
  ])

